# Getting images src in Selenium

Tags: java, html, image, selenium

I asked this question but needed help again.
 I'm trying to get all image src in the page to check if there is not loaded image in the page.
I used these codes but it takes  all images src's .How can I take only these srcs in **"butik-large-image"** class.

Here are my codes:

```
List<WebElement> srcClass;
        String [] cats={"TÜM BUTİKLER","KADIN","ERKEK","ÇOCUK","SPOR GİYİM","AYAKKABI & ÇANTA","SAAT & "
                + "AKSESUAR","KOZMETİK","EV & YAŞAM","HIZLI TESLİMAT"}; 
        for (String kat : cats) {
            sleep(1000);
            clickObjectByLinkText(kat);
            srcClass = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
               System.out.println(kat +" için image src linkleri");
               for (WebElement src : srcClass){
                   if(src.getAttribute("src").equals(null))
                       System.out.println("Ekranda "+kat+" " + " kategorisi için image yüklenemeyen data bulundu,lütfen aşagıdaki pathleri inceleyiniz..");
                   System.out.println(src.getAttribute("src"));
               }
               System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
               srcClass.clear();
               }
```

My html source:

```
<div class="butik-large-image">
                <a href="/Olgun-Orkun-x-Deniz-Akkaya-nin-Sectikleriyle---Kadin-Tekstil/ButikDetay/174246/Kadin" style="font-size: 0" 
title="Olgun Orkun x Deniz Akkaya'nın Seçtikleriyle - Kadın Tekstil" 
class="butik-img-size">
                    <img class="bigBoutiqueImage lazy-load-trigger loaded" 
**src="https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com//Assets/ProductImages/OA/CampaignVisual/OriginalBoutiqueImages/13520/llardau3_0_new.jpg**" data-original="https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com//Assets/ProductImages/OA/CampaignVisual/OriginalBoutiqueImages/13520/llardau3_0_new.jpg" title="Olgun Orkun x Deniz Akkaya'nın Seçtikleriyle - Kadın Tekstil" onerror="this.src='/Resources/images/bigBoutiquePlaceHolder.png'" alt="Olgun Orkun x Deniz Akkaya'nın Seçtikleriyle - Kadın Tekstil">
                    <div class="efect">
</div>
                </a>
</div>
```

Comment: i have added an answer for this. Please check and let me know your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is :

- Get all the elements by className "butik-large-image"
- Get all the elements having img tag
- write your desired code ex : get src image link, img exits or not etc.

The complete implementation for your desired requirement is below:

```
 List<WebElement> allImagesUnderThisClass = driver.findElements(By.className("butik-large-image"));
    String ignoreImageURl = "https://www.trendyol.com/Resources/images/bigBoutiquePlaceHolder.png";
    for(WebElement elem : allImagesUnderThisClass){
        List<WebElement> imgs = elem.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
        for(WebElement img : imgs){
            String source = img.getAttribute("src");
            if(!source.equalsIgnoreCase(ignoreImageURl)){
                System.out.println(source); 
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: I did but it takes strange img src as in the below:

Comment: it is getting 3 correct images src then it takes https://www.trendyol.com/Resources/images/bigBoutiquePlaceHolder.png images for each categories. Also my study link is  https://www.trendyol.com for this site tabs Im getting the images src for all boutique

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your current requirement. Also you can change the logic by urself. Please let me know your feedback

Comment: @little glad to hear from you that it worked for you. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can look for `<img>` tag under an element with `butik-large-image` class

```
srcClass = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".butik-large-image img"));
```

The space between the class and tag means any descendant.